# YUV4:2:0 conversion to RGB outputs overly green image

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg, h.264, direct3d

I'm decoding video and getting YUV 420 frames. In order to render them using D3D11, they need to get converted to RGB (or at least I assume that the render target view cannot be YUV itself).

The YUV frames are all in planar format, meaning UV and not packed. I'm creating 3 textures and ShaderResourceViews of type `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM`. I'm copying each plane from the frame into it's own ShaderResourceView. I'm then relying on the sampler to account for the differences in size between the Y and UV planes. Black/White only looks great. If I add in color though, I get an overly Green Picture:
[image]

I'm at a huge loss of what I could be doing wrong.. I've tried switching the UV and planes around, I've also tried tweaking the conversion values. I'm following [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/recommended-8-bit-yuv-formats-for-video-rendering?redirectedfrom=MSDN) on picture conversion.

Here is my shader:

```
min16float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    float y = YChannel.Sample(defaultSampler, input.texCoord).r;
    float u = UChannel.Sample(defaultSampler, input.texCoord).r - 0.5;
    float v = VChannel.Sample(defaultSampler, input.texCoord).r - 0.5;

    float r = y + 1.13983 * v;
    float g = y - 0.39465 * u - 0.58060 * v;
    float b = y + 2.03211 * u;

    return min16float4(r, g, b , 1.f);
}
```

Creating my ShaderResourceViews:

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&texDesc, sizeof(texDesc));
    texDesc.Width = 1670;
    texDesc.Height = 626;
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    texDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    texDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;


    dev->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, NULL, &pYPictureTexture);
    dev->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, NULL, &pUPictureTexture);
    dev->CreateTexture2D(&texDesc, NULL, &pVPictureTexture);
    
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

    dev->CreateShaderResourceView(pYPictureTexture, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &pYPictureTextureResourceView);

    dev->CreateShaderResourceView(pUPictureTexture, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &pUPictureTextureResourceView);
    
    dev->CreateShaderResourceView(pVPictureTexture, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &pVPictureTextureResourceView);
```

And then How I'm copying the decoded ffmpeg AVFrames:

```
    int height = 626;
    int width = 1670;    

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE msY;
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE msU;
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE msV;
    devcon->Map(pYPictureTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &msY);

    memcpy(msY.pData, frame->data[0], height * width);
    devcon->Unmap(pYPictureTexture, 0);

    devcon->Map(pUPictureTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &msU);
    memcpy(msU.pData, frame->data[1], (height*width) / 4);
    devcon->Unmap(pUPictureTexture, 0);


    devcon->Map(pVPictureTexture, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &msV);
    memcpy(msV.pData, frame->data[2], (height*width) / 4);
    devcon->Unmap(pVPictureTexture, 0);
```

PS: Happy to provide any more additional requested code! I just wanted to be concise as possible.

Comment: Since U and V resolution is `width/2` x `height/2`, we can't use `input.texCoord` in `u = UChannel.Sample(defaultSampler, input.texCoord).r` and `float v = ...`. for `u` and `v`, scale the coordinate position by `0.5`. I think there are other issues, but the code you have posted is too partial for testing.

Comment: Thanks, I will wire this up and test now. I can post more code, just lmk what you need to see.

Comment: @Rotem That didn't seem to work, it just made the output image larger. At least if I am understanding you correctly, i did: `input.texCoord * 0.5` for only the U and V Channels. My understanding is that texture coordinates are floats between 0 and 1 with (1,1) being the bottom right and (0,0) being the top left, therefore it would all ready "Scale for us" so to speak. I could be wrong though because I am a noob with D3D.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the issue! Basically, I had the equation wrong.

For anyone ever trying to convert `AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P` (Planar YUV 4:2:0) to a `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` Direct3D 2DTexture:

```
// Derived from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206750(v=vs.85).aspx
    // Section: Converting 8-bit YUV to RGB888

    float3 yuv = (y, u, v);

    // These values are calculated from (16 / 255) and (128 / 255)
    
    float C = y - 0.062745f;
    float D = u - 0.501960f;
    float E = v - 0.501960f;

    yuv.r = 1.164383f * C + 1.596027f * E  ;
    yuv.g = 1.164383f * C - (0.391762f * D) - (0.812968f * E) ;
    yuv.b = 1.164383f * C + 2.017232f * D ;

    return saturate(yuv);
```

The exact reason for my problem, is that it was miscalculating the Green Value. It was never under `0.4` or above `0.5` (event for white or black colors). Make sure you always follow specifications as closely as possible!